# Android LazyLoading Gridview Images with title?

Tags: android, gridview, android-image

I am currently creating a app that I want to load a List of data into from a database and then  display that data in a GridView. I have created the connection to the database and have pulled back and populated the GridView successfully. The issue I am having is that on my list row layout I want to be able to setLayoutParams so that the images can be cropped and all be the same size and this will then not cause issues on other device sizes.

The files I have are below:

**list_row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">



    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/list_image"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />


</LinearLayout>
```

**ListAdapter.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DressesAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

    public DressesAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
        activity = a;
        data=d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

        ImageView thumb_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image); // thumb image
        //thumb_image.setLayoutParams(new ImageView.LayoutParams(70, 70));

        HashMap<String, String> dress = new HashMap<String, String>();
        dress = data.get(position);

        imageLoader.DisplayImage(dress.get(DressListActivity.TAG_IMAGE), thumb_image);
        return vi;
    }
}
```

**ListActivity.java**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/grid_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >  

</GridView>
```

The error I get when running this is below:

```
04-06 14:02:18.260: E/AndroidRuntime(12798): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams
```

I hope someone can help me correct this issue as its really annoying, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the approach I am using to show a Grid with 3 pictures that fit across the device with titles TextView for each one.

It formats correctly on all devices.

All of my pictures are portrait with aspect ratio of 1.5, such as 300 px height by 200 px wide. (This is the 3.0 and 1.5 you see in the sizing function and change per needs).

I use portrait for my layouts.

Hope you can get it working, its tricky. This works very well for me.

set up your GridView and its Adapter such as this:

```
// create grid and adapter
gridAdapter = new SET UP YOUR ADAPTER HERE; 
    grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid);
    grid.setAdapter(YOUR ADAPTER);
    grid.setFadingEdgeLength(0);
    int picHeight = Utils.getGridPicHeight(MainActivity.this);
    int picLength = (int) ((float)picHeight / 1.5);
    grid.setColumnWidth(picLength);
```

And the Utils.getGridPicHeight:

```
    public static int getGridPicHeight (Activity activity) { 
        DisplayMetrics dMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dMetrics);
        // give back a % of the screen width for the height
        final float WIDE = activity.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
        int value = (int)(WIDE / 3.0f * 1.5f);
        return value;
}
```

and very important, in your adapter, you have to set the images like this:

```
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params;

        int picHeight = Utils.getGridPicHeight(activity);
        int picLength = (int) ((float)picHeight / 1.5);
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(picLength,picHeight);
        params.gravity=Gravity.CENTER;
        params.height=picHeight;
        params.width=picLength;
        image.setLayoutParams(params);
```

grid_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
    />
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/imgTit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:maxLines="1" 
        android:gravity="center" 
        android:layout_gravity="center">
    </TextView> 
</LinearLayout>
```

and then in your GridView inside a LinearLayout

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center">   
        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/grid"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:numColumns="3"
            android:horizontalSpacing="4dp"
            android:verticalSpacing="4dp"
            android:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I am trying to implement the code and I think I am almost there I just need to know on the adapter what to set the params variable as as at the moment it says "params cannot be resolved to a variable"? Do I need to initalise it at the top as something? Thanks

Comment: Ok i think I am almost there I just need to know how to modify your solution so I can have the images on their own and being display within 1dp from each other, any ideas?

Comment: For the PARAMS declaration, here is how i declare it: **bold**LinearLayout.LayoutParams params;

Comment: I just added my param declaration to the adapter excerpt above, sorry for not including it. Not quite sure what you mean about "images on their own". This should be a 3-wide layout with 4dp spacing that fills the screen width.

Answer (score 0):

The `Exception` is caused by simply `import`ing the wrong `LayoutParams` subclass. Maybe it's easiest to write `new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(` explicitly.

Unrelated but also `scaleType` of `ImageView` might come handy.